# Dudas sobre la autenticación por token JWT

Tags: api, autenticación, jwt

Buenas, 
estoy desarrollando una API y tengo la siguiente duda sobre la autenticación.

En principio iba a aplicar la conocida **JWT**. Es decir, me llega usuario y contraseña, genero el token según JWT y devuelvo el mismo. A partir de ahí las siguientes peticiones a la api deben llevar ese token para tratar al usuario como autenticado. Al llegar dicho token debo comprobar que está bien formado y descrifrarlo para obener la información correspondiente.

Mi duda es la siguiente. Y si genero un token (no JWT) propio y lo guardo en base de datos con los datos que necesite ?? De esta manera me evito el proceso de descifrar el token. Cuando venga una petición con token, compruebo que está en la tabla y listo. De todas formas la sesión correspondiente la guardo en bd así que ¿Puede ser innecesario el token JWT?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La idea de usar JWT es precisamente no depender de la sesión. Es útil cuando estás usando una API REST, porque por definición es "Stateless" (sin estado, sin sesión)

Comment: Correcto pero eso quiere decir que, por ejemplo no se puede obtener de la api el número de usuarios conectados en un momento dado??
Entonces ¿Cada vez que me llega una petición con token debo comprobar el token y después obtener y generar toda la información necesaria sobre el usaurio en función de la petición??
Por ejemplo los permisos asignados al usuario, las comunidades a las que pertenece, las conversaciones del foro en las que puede participar etc, todo esto habría que obtenerlo cada vez?? No se cachea en tablas?

Comment: Una vez que obtienes el ID de usuario (desencriptando el JWT o buscando el hash de un token en la BBDD) el trabajo de traer las entidades relacionadas al usuario vas a tener que hacerlo sí o sí

Comment: Es que el concepto de usuario conectado no existe en las API REST, el protocolo HTTP no es orientado a conexión, así que sólo puedes sacar estadísticas del número de peticiones o el número de usuarios distintos conectados en un periodo de tiempo

Answer (score 1):

Como dice @PabloLozano, con JWT sólo interactúas **una vez** con la BBDD para generar el token y de ahí en adelante sólo desencriptas el token obtenido (usando una llave `JSON Web Signature (JWS)` presente en tu servidor) para validar el JWT.

Este flujo implica que el JWT es un objeto json **encriptado** que puede ser **desencriptado** con la llave JWS.

Lo que estás proponiendo, en cambio, acerca de generar un token, y almacenarlo **en base de datos**, para luego comprobar cada siguiente petición con otra consulta a la BBDD es más bien el flujo de una autenticación Oauth2.

Los protocolos para generar un token de Oauth2 implican `hashing` y el hash obtenido no se puede "deshashear" para saber nada acerca de él. Sólo puedes compararlo con  una tabla de tokens almacenados.

En resumen: son peras con manzanas, pero **si realmente quisieras** hacer ese flujo manualmente sí podrías guardar el JWT en la BBDD y tratarlo como si fuera un token Oauth2 de ahí en adelante.